# Extracting data through mongoose

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, iot

I am new to nodejs and react,I was trying to build IOT based weather station for which I am storing data in Mongodb.
As I can send data from my sensors to mongodb now I need to extract and send it to the frontend react but I wasn't able to get data from it I have tried learning on many blogs and documentation but I am missing something.

[Mongodb data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97kCJ.png)

This is the form of data present in my mongodb.
Can anyone help me develop the backend part for getting data or have any solution for this.

Comment: do you want to get data at your frontend side automatically or only when you call for it. ?

Comment: yes I am trying to get data to my react frontend. I was extracting data through to nodejs  using monogoose but their some issue I can' understand as I don't have much idea

Comment: can you help me to develop this whole mern development for the project would be great help of yours

Comment: make an API in nodejs, which run find query using mongoose, and just return your result in response of API ,  and use that API call from frontend

Comment: I don't understand the route  part

Comment: better to search and check some basic example of node